# How to add multiple JDKs to Eclipse via eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to add multiple JDKs to eclipse using the **-vm** in **eclipse.ini**
I tried giving a comma separated list and as well giving multiple -vm params.

But that did not work.

When I add multiple JDKs via Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs it is applicable to only that workspace.
When I switch workspace or add a new workspace I get only the JDK that was defined as the -vm parameter in eclipse.ini

I've got this requirement because our code base is using Java 8 but the build system requires JDK 6 as an installed JRE

Comment: There is no support for this. The -vm is just the JVM used to run Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

The `-vm` switch is still present and used in installations of Eclipse *that don't have the Java tools at all*. It only controls which VM is used to run Eclipse itself. It has *nothing* to do with adding entries to the Installed JREs preference page once a workspace has been created.

Comment: @GhostCat the question is how to do it with the -VM switch or eclipse ini, so I see this as a valid answer ("not designed for the task")

Comment: Revising my opinion on your answer; and a +1, also as "thanks" for your great edit on my other answer on eclipse keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that different **workspaces** *share* such information, you have to use the -configuration command line switch.

I have a wrapper script to start eclipse that looks like this:

```
env SWT_GTK3=0 UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 /opt/eclipse-neon/eclipse -configuration /data/eclipse-neon/configuration
```

Using that wrapper, I can turn to different workspaces, but as said, their *configuration* is coming from one single place (that directory /data/eclipse-neon/configuration)

Edit: I think what you are asking for (how to specify various JDK/JREs to be available to be "selected" later on) on command line ... is simply not possible. You see, when you use the preferences menu to *add* a new runtime there, that causes a "lot of activity" - which makes it into various configuration files on the drive.

In other words: like any other preference, the set of available runtimes is a **configuration** element of eclipse; therefore controlled by files in the configuration directory.

Thus, I still think: sharing the *configuration* folder is the only reasonable way to have multiple workspaces use the same runtimes.

Edit again: the only idea left: do "reverse engineering". Simply make a copy of all config files of your current eclipse setup. Then start eclipse, add a new runtime, end eclipse. Then compare which new config files were created, and check the existing ones for changes. That might give you a clue how to that automatically.

Comment: I don't exactly want different workspaces to share information. I just want that all the workspaces have 2 JDKs by default. And if that is not possible via the eclipse.ini I can use -configuration command line option as well. But in that case can you tell me how to specify multiple JDKs in the external configuration file that I provide

Comment: Not exactly @GhostCat. What I am looking at is for a way to specify multiple JDKs in the configuration file (that I feed via the -configuration param) so what when I go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs I see all those JDKs